# How do different structures for storing date and time in programming languages and databases work?

Tags: database, datetime, programming-languages

Given that languages and databases use different structures for storing date and time, what piece of code is responsible for transforming the date and time data structure when moving the date and time value from programming language to database and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most systems store DATETIME as a floating point number.  The value to the left of the decimal point is the number of days from day zero(0). Day zero can be anything.  In Unix, day 0 is 1/1/1970. The year of Unix birth. However, this is not very intuitive to the average user. Oracle uses the actual year 0 and SQL Server uses 1/1/1900.

Convert the number 0 to a DATETIME and you'll get that systems Day 0.

The numbers to the right of the decimal point is the time. This can be recorded in milliseconds, microseconds, whatever granularity your system can handle.

The best part of this method is date math becomes very simple.  Converting the number to the actual date and time is were all the complexity is involved.

Most programming languages will follow this same pattern.

Comment: "Most systems store DATETIME as a floating point number" - I don't believe that's actually the case. In my experience, it's usually an integer - a number of nanoseconds, microseconds, milliseconds or seconds since the Unix epoch.

Comment: The "store an integer" approach applies for C, Java and .NET at least. I know there *are* some systems that use floating point numbers, but I don't believe they're in the majority. Aside from anything else, you end up with variable precision depending on the date, which is pretty odd.

Comment: Storing two integers, e.g. one for "days since an epoch" or "seconds since an epoch" and another integer for the finer-grained precision is also common - but that's not the same as it being a floating point number.

Comment: Thanks Mendolis, Jon. So what I get is that most programming languages and databases use one of the few ways described above. Another part of my question was, how does datetime data get transferred between a programming language and a database using different format to store dates. What I get is that this to and fro conversion is responsibility of a data access libraries like ADO.NET.

Comment: Two parter:  I have found no documentation but the simple answer:  It is formatted as a string.  ISO standard 8601 was created for this exact purpose.  It details the sharing of date and time values.  The values CAN NOT be shipped from one system as binary for simple fact that some CPU's are little endian and some are big endian.

Comment: Endianess determines how the bits in a byte are read. Big - the are read from left to right. Little - from right to left.  Therefore, data can not be shipped in binary form without translation.  In fact, Intel CPUs are little endian but ethernet is defined as big endian.  In many cases, the network card must flip the bits both when sent and received.

Comment: Thanks @Mendolis, In addition. Depending on specific DB implementation of the datetime, time zone might or might not be part of the datetime data type. In SQL Server one has to know before hand that for what time zone was the datetime stored in the DB. Whereas in an implementation like that of [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/), time zone is irrelevant as all times are values in milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970 UTC. The same implementation is followed by [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) language.

Comment: As with all things database, 'It depends'.  The GETDATE() function returns the server DATETIME (time zone specific). SYSDATETIME returns UTC time. - It amazes me that dates are stored as milliseconds.  Seems really wasteful to me. After all, 1bil seconds is only 31yrs.  Milliseconds is less than 12days.  As a floating point (from 1/1/1900), 31yrs is:   11322.4583.  Can store a LOT more time in a smaller space....   Still, to each their own.